# Prob. 3, Sec. 9, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Injections $f_n:\{1,\ldots,n\}\longrightarrow A$ implies the existence of ...

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a set and $\left\{f_n \right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a given indexed family of injective functions
$$f_n \colon \{1, \ldots, n\} \longrightarrow A.$$
Then (I can) show that $A$ is infinite.

How to define an injective function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow A$ without using the choice axiom?

My effort:

> Let
> $$f(1) \colon= f_1(1).$$
> Now as $f_2 \colon \{1, 2\} \longrightarrow A$ is injective, we must have $f_2(1) \neq f_2(2)$.
> So we can conclude that either $f_2(1) \neq f_1(1)$ or $f_2(2) \neq f_1(1)$.
> That is, either $f_2(1) \neq f(1)$ or $f_2(2) \neq f(1)$.

> So the set $f \big(\{1, 2 \}\big) - f\big(\{1 \}\big)$ has at least one element.

> Let $k_1$ be the smaller  element of the set $\{1,2\}$ such that $f_2 \left(k_1 \right) \neq f_1(1)$. We define $f(2) \colon= f_2 \left( k_1 \right)$.

> Then $f(2) \neq f(1)$.

> Now $f_3 \colon \{1, 2, 3\} \longrightarrow A$ is injctive, so the set $f_3\big(\{1,2,3\}\big)$ has exactly three elements, whereas the set $f\big(\{1,2\}\big)$ has exactly two elements. Thus the set $f_3\big(\{1,2,3\}\big) - f\big(\{1,2\} \big)$ has at least one element.

> Let $k_2$ be the smallest element of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \}$ such that $f_3 \left( k_2 \right) \not\in f\big(\{1,2\}\big)$.

> Let's define $f(3) \colon= f_3 \left( k_2 \right)$.

> Then $f(3) \not\in f\big(\{1,2\} \big)$. So $f(3) \neq f(1)$ and $f(3) \neq f(2)$.

> Suppose that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq 2$, and suppose also that $f(1), \ldots, f(n)$ have beeen defined so that $f(i) \neq f(j)$ for any $i , j\in \{1, \ldots, n \}$ such that $i \neq j$.

> Now as the function $f_{n+1} \colon \{ 1, \ldots, n+1 \} \longrightarrow A$ is injective, the set $f_{n+1}\big( \{1, \ldots, n+1 \}\big)$ has exactly $n+1$ elements. On the other hand, the set $f\big(\{1,\ldots, n\}\big)$ has exactly $n$ elements. So the set $f_{n+1}\big(\{1, \ldots, n+1 \}\big) - f\big(\{1,\ldots, n\}\big)$ has at least one element.

> Let $k_n$ be the smallest element of the set $\{1, \ldots, n+1\}$ such that $f_{n+1} \left(k_n \right) \not\in f\big(\{1,\ldots, n\}\big)$. So let's define
> $f(n+1) \colon= f_{n+1} \left( k_n \right)$.

> Obviously, $f(n+1) \neq f(i)$ for any $i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$.

> In this way, we have defined a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow A$ such that $f(m) \neq f(n)$ for any $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m>n$.

Is this proof good enough? If so, then is it rigorous enough? Or, are there issues of correctness or rigor?

Comment: I guess you need the axiom of (at least dependent) choice, to get $f$ since you define $f$ recursively. For the rest, the proof (and the idea) is right.

Comment: @Andre: No Choice is needed, actually. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Choice is needed! Your proof looks just fine, and proceeds by the Principle of Countable Recursion. You could even shorten it as follows:

> We define $f:\Bbb N\to A$ by recursion as follows. Let 
>   $$f(1) \colon= f_1(1).$$
>
> Suppose that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $f$ has been injectively-defined on $\{1,...,n\}.$
>
> Now as the function $f_{n+1} \colon \{ 1, \ldots, n+1 \} \to A$ is injective, the set $f_{n+1}\left(\{1, \ldots, n+1 \}\right)$ has exactly $n+1$ elements. On the other hand, the set $f\left(\{1,\ldots, n\}\right)$ has exactly $n$ elements. So the set $f_{n+1}\left(\{1, \ldots, n+1 \}\right) - f\left(\{1,\ldots, n\}\right)$ has at least one element.

At this stage, one could simply rely on the Axiom of Dependent Choice, and conclude that there is a function $f:\Bbb N\to A$ such that $f(1)=f_1(1)$ and such that $f(n+1)\in f_{n+1}\left(\{1, \ldots, n+1 \}\right) - f\left(\{1,\ldots, n\}\right)$ for all $n.$ Fortunately, we don't have to!

> Let $k_n$ be the smallest element of the set $\{1, \ldots, n+1\}$ such that $f_{n+1}(k_n) \not\in f\left(\{1,\ldots, n\}\right),$ and let 
>   $$f(n+1) \colon= f_{n+1}(k_n).$$

By taking the *smallest* element in each successive step, you explicitly describe the recursive construction, thereby eliminating any reliance on Choice.